# change button color after saved data

Tags: reactjs

[image]Here I have created one React component where I Want to show questions in a box and the question will change after clicking the number of the questions if the save button will be called then want to change question's color which questions are saved how can I achieve this?

```
import React, {  useState } from "react";
function Counter(){
const data=[{questionId:"1",desc:"question1"},{questionId:"2",desc:"question2"}]

const [currentData,setCurrentData] =useState('')
const [active,setActive] =useState('yellow')
const [savedData,setSavedData] =useState()

function handleClick(data){
   setCurrentData(data)
}
function handleSave(data){
    console.log(data)
    setSavedData(data) 
 }


return(
    <>
    <div style={{display:"flex",justifyContent:"center"}}>
      <div style={{border:"2px solid red",height:"50vh",width:"50vw"}}>

         {currentData}
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <button onClick={()=>{
               handleSave(currentData)
    }}>Save</button>


      {data.map((item,i)=>{
              return(
                 <button onClick={()=>handleClick(item.questionId)} 
       style={{backgroundColor:active}}>{`Q ${i+1}`}</button>
              )
          })}
          </>
       )
         }
            export default Counter;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to change the color of the question that you selected after clicking save?

You can do this by changing the color of the text on your div with the question
Inside the style object, just add:

```
color: currentData === savedData ? "red" : "black"
```

You check if the question that is being displayed matches the question that was saved and changes its color